# MySQL: Better few tables with millions of rows or thousands of tables with hundrets of rows

Tags: mysql, database-design, scalability

I'm building an web application and I want to make it scale from the start. I'm not very much into Database scalability and I'm facing this doubts:

Should I use a handful of tables with millions of rows or shall I split stuff into hundreds of tables if not thousands of tables with expectedly hundreds of rows.

I can go both routs but I don't know which one will scale better in the long run.

I found some info on this tread, but it's not helping much: [MySQL Whats better for speed one table with millions of rows or managing multiple tables?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13765716/mysql-whats-better-for-speed-one-table-with-millions-of-rows-or-managing-multipl)

Basically I need to know, it's better to scale a database vertically or horizontally?

Comment: Millions of rows is not a big number, so for maintainability reasons it's better to have just enough tables to match your business requirements.

Comment: This totally depends on the specific case. It depends on the schema and the query patterns and the amount of dev time you are willing to expend.

Comment: it also depends on the size of each row and the number of tables you would involve at a time

Answer (score 4):

Databases will give responses fast enough if queries are adjusted well, there may be magical changes in speed with very small adjustments in queries.

However, you don't want a lecture in databases. To your question: The most important thing here is to achieve normalization forms.

Your tables should be managable and [redundancy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_redundancy)-free. To avoid redundancy, you need to [normalize](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization) your tables as much as possible. Normalization forms are up to 6NF, but I think [Boyce–Codd normal form](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boyce%E2%80%93Codd_normal_form) should be enough, if you're not experienced in the area.

Answer (score 2):

Well said by Ismet. However, dealing with the web, sometimes, people have certain 'aggregates' or other totals they want to keep track of and can be somewhat time consuming.

If you might have such categories, it might be a good consideration to "tack-on" some extra column(s) as necessary for such entries.  Then, when records are added to whatever table(s), insert/update triggers can be run to just update these values vs having to explicitly rerun a full query that is pulling from millions of records and give you a performance hit.